# console.log doesn't show a message after fetch

Tags: javascript, console, fetch

I would like to understand why my function doesn't show any message in the console. Everything else works. The state is being updated with the fetched data and rendered in the react template. 
I guess it doens't show the data in console because it's async but why it doesn't show the simple string -> console.log("START") console.log("END")?

```
const clickSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
  console.log("START") // <- why it's not shown?
  const signup = async (name, email, password) => {
      const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/user/signup`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ name, email, password })
      })
      const data = await res.json();
      await setValues({ ...values, error: data.message, logged: data.status });
      console.log(data)
      return data;
    };

    const data = await signup(name, email, password)
    console.log(data);
    console.log("END") // <- why it's not shown?
  };
```

Comment: don't `await` things that aren't Promises. `.json()` isn't a promise, `setValues()` isn't a promise (probably). put a `console.log()` at the top and make sure `clickSubmit()` is even getting called - it very well might not be. if it's not showing "END", the code simply is not being run. do you at least get anything from all the `console.log(data)`?

Comment: yes, the code works properly, the new user is being created and if there's an error the error is being shown in the react component.
<div>{error}<div> is updated correctly. I know I could put it in the console.log in the front but I just wonder why it doesn't wokt if it's at the end.

Comment: it also doesn't work on the top.

Comment: @Klaycon `response.json()` *does* return a promise

Comment: only console.log doesn't work

Comment: @Bergi oops, you're right, of course. Always forget that with the fetch API, it never made any sense to me since parsing as JSON should be a synchronous task.

Comment: @Klaycon It's not just parsing JSON, it's waiting for the body of the HTTP stream to complete

Answer (score 0):

If as you have mentioned that out of **async** call is not even working, then it may be the **messages** in chrome Dev tools is not selected, to fix this issue, click on **consolde sidebar**, and make sure that **messages** (first in the list) is selected. Like in below image (32 messages is selected).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

---

I accidentally added a filter to the browser. removing it brought everything back to norm.